# How to copy and paste between different tmux panes running vim instances

Tags: vim, vi, tmux

Example: copy in one tmux pane (via vim), then switch to another pane (running another vim instance) and paste using the vim paste command. I know this can be done via tmux (using prefix+]) but it would be really handy if I can copy and paste using vim bindings since i'm just switching between different panes running vim.

Any ideas?

Comment: are the tmux panes running vim on different hosts? If not I'd just run a single instance of vim and use vim buffers to open the 2 files and paste between buffers.

Comment: this may be an issue with your version of vim not being compile with clipboard support - see @DmitrySemenov's answer below

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sorry, I'm trying to convince you to use vim built-in features.

---

To make the `copy/paste` easy, you can open files in another Tabpages:

```
:tabe /path/to/another/file
```

Use <kbd>gt</kbd> or <kbd>gT</kbd> to switch Tabpages.

---

Or split the window to edit another file:

```
:sp /path/to/another/file
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl-w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to switch Windows.
To split the window vertically, please use `:vsp file`

---

#### Update:

This is my `.tmux.conf` file:

```
# vim
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind [ copy-mode
bind -t vi-copy v begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy y copy-selection
bind -t vi-copy V rectangle-toggle
bind ] paste-buffer

# buffer
bind Space choose-buffer
```

I only use them when I need to copy terminal output.

Comment: or rotate buffers, kev what about copying to the clipboard?

Comment: Is there no way to do it directly via tmux? I have different panes open in different directories and sometimes it's not convenient to :tabe or :sp and type out the long path. Much easier to switch the panes and paste.

Comment: I leave the `prefix-[,]` as default. Because I have learned them by heart.  You can config them to what you want.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It hit prefix [, then v, then I move to another line, then y, then prefix ], but nothing happens, even after I restart tmux.

Comment: I think there are reasons to not just use a single vim instance. For instance, you might want only three panes open in your terminal: one half-screen editing session, a fourth-screen editing session, and a fourth-screen terminal. I'm not sure this can be accomplished with one instance of vim.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to use several Vim instances.  For example, what if I have two monitors, but I want to edit files on both of them?  Or what if I have several tmux sessions for completely different projects, but I want to copy some text from a file in one project to a file in another?  Being stuck with a single, system-wide Vim instance is very inflexible.  Vim is a text editor, not an operating system.

Comment: For newer versions of tmux, it is `bind-key -T copy-mode-vi ...` instead of `bind-key -t vi-copy ...`

Answer (score 24):

I've been used this handy binding for several years :)

```
" copy to buffer
vmap <C-c> :w! ~/.vimbuffer<CR>
nmap <C-c> :.w! ~/.vimbuffer<CR>
" paste from buffer
map <C-p> :r ~/.vimbuffer<CR>
```

Comment: Exactly, it didn't copy to system clipboard. 
But it fulfill the requirement of this issue then :)

Comment: interesting solution. you could use a script for the copy to generate a new date based filename every time in a directory, and then use another script for the paste to read from the most recent filename. Now you can keep a trace of all your clipboards too.

Answer (score 14):

I'm currently stuck with a laptop running Windows at work, but I do all my development on a server running Linux, so I end up working in a tmux session over PuTTY all day.

I wanted to copy text between vim instances running in different windows in my tmux session. I tried using the `*` register to copy to the system clipboard, but since I'm connected through PuTTY I don't have an X session, so there *is* no system clipboard, even if I launch gVim instead of vim. (I might have been able to use x-forwarding or something to fix this, but I didn't want to install an x-server on windows.)

I thought that there should be a way to use the tmux copy/paste buffer from vim in place of the system keyboard, and sure enough someone has written [a plugin for that](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip).

Installing fakeclip adds a new register, `&`, which maps to tmux's paste buffer. Since all my vim instances are within the same tmux session, this makes it super simple to yank/put text between them.

The plugin documentation says that fakeclip should also work with gnu screen, but I haven't personally tested that.

---

**tl;dr**

Install the [fakeclip](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip) plugin, and then you can use <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to *yank* into tmux's buffer, and <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>&</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to *put* from tmux's buffer.

Answer (score 13):

Although I agree that it's better to just use one vim instance, you can do this with tmux alone. It has a built in copy-mode. My tmux.conf is set up like:

```
  setw -g mode-keys vi
  unbind [
  unbind p
  bind C-y copy-mode
  bind p paste-buffer
  bind -t vi-copy v begin-selection
  bind -t vi-copy y copy-selection
  bind -t vi-copy Escape cancel
```

So you can use `prefix-<C-y>` to activate copy mode, `/search term` as an example to go where you want, `v` to visually select, `y` to yank into tmux. Then go to other vim session and get into insert mode. Use `prefix-p` to paste what's in the tmux paste buffer. There are also ways to copy tmux's paste buffer to your system clipboard.

Comment: Why is it better to use one vim instance?  Surely this is incompatible with the idea of having different workspaces?  It doesn't seem very practical when I have 5 large, unrelated projects to work on.

Comment: Mostly a matter of opinion and/or CPU efficiency. Here's a video to watch: https://vimeo.com/4446112

Answer (score 4):

You can copy the content to clipboard using vim bindings, then switch to the pane and paste it.
The following key-bindings might be handy.

```
noremap ty "+y
noremap tY "+Y  // copy a whole line to the clipboard
noremap tp "+p  // put the text from clipboard after the cursor 
noremap tP "+P  // put the text from clipboard before the cursor
```

The `"+` register is used to access system's clipborad in Vim.

Some useful tips:
1. You can press `v` or `V` or `ctrl-v` to enter visual mode, then select the content you want to yank, and press `ty` to copy it to your clipboard.
2. `ty` can be combined with other motions. For instance, `tyaw` can be used to copy a word under the cursor to the clipboard. `tyib` copy the content inside parentheses. `tyi"` copy the text inside double quotation, etc...

See also [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard) for further explanation.

Comment: For the sake of anyone who may not know those commands, could you add an explanation of each one?  It would make the answer more useful!

Comment: @PetahChristian I am quite surprised that my answer should be noticed! I expand my answer now. If there is something ambiguous or grammar mistakes(I 'm not a native English speaker), please let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

This works in neovim.

Execute `:checkhealth`, you will find something like these:

```
## Clipboard (optional)
  - OK: Clipboard tool found: tmux
```

If not, maybe you need to upgrade the tmux to the latest version 2.9.

Then add the following code in '~/config/nvim/init.vim'

```
set clipboard+=unnamedplus
```

Answer (score 2):

**solution on Fedora24**

you need to use **vimx** instead of **vim**

put in your .bashrc or .zshrc

```
alias vi='vimx'
alias vim='vimx'
```

and then you can easily copy between vims/tmux panels

---

```
$ vim --version | grep clipboard
-clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      -toolbar
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_clipboard

$ vimx --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +toolbar
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xterm_clipboard
```

vimx is part of vim-enhanced-2:7.4.1868-1.fc24.x86_64 you most likely have installed

Answer (score -1):

**control+insert** = copy

**shift+insert** = paste