# Copy and Paste using System clipboard without using Paste mode?

Tags: vim

I'd like to be able to copy and paste using the system clipboard without having to toggle paste mode every time. Is there a way to do that?

If it matters at all, I'm using vim from the terminal on a Mac.

Comment: Seems repeated topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to safely paste or copy raw text in the terminal without having to [`:set paste`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27paste%27) beforehand and `:set nopaste` afterwards? Or do you mean you want commands like [`y`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#y) and [`p`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#p) to copy to and paste from the system clipboard by default?

Comment: Like on *every* other UNIX-like system, the default Vim doesn't have built-in clipboard support so you must install a proper one. On Mac OS X, your best bet is MacVim.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean you want to be able to safely paste or copy raw text in the terminal without having to type [`:set paste`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27paste%27) beforehand and `:set nopaste` afterwards, you have a few options.

- Set the `'pastetoggle'` option. See [`:help 'pastetoggle'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27pastetoggle%27), which gives this usage example:

  ```
  :map <F10> :set paste<CR>
  :map <F11> :set nopaste<CR>
  :imap <F10> <C-O>:set paste<CR>
  :imap <F11> <nop>
  :set pastetoggle=<F11>
  ```
- Create [mappings](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html) for `:set paste` and `:set nopaste`, like in the above code.
- Install the plugin [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired). It [provides mappings `yo` and `yO`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/1bf6f167d4994d7e899a5b27a627e91490850508/doc/unimpaired.txt#L104-L108) that `:set paste`, do `o` or `O`, and then automatically `:set nopaste` when you exit Insert mode.

---

If you mean you want commands like [`y`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#y) and [`p`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#p) to copy to and paste from the system clipboard by default, then just see the existing question [How to make Vim paste from (and copy to) system’s clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11489428/578288)

Comment: I mean that I'd like to be able to paste text into vim using the system keyboard without having to toggle paste mode before and after I paste.