# How can I paste the contents of the system clipboard into all files in the argument list?

Tags: vim

How can I paste the contents of the system clipboard to all files in the argument list in Vim?

Comment: Is there a question in here?

Comment: I wanna do Q/A style but  I had it already written - why can't I write it in 1 post like first the the question and then the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
:argdo execute 'normal! "+p' | w
```

Explanation:

- `:argdo` Run the command that follows on each file in the argument list. Alternatively, you can use `:windo` to run a command on each window, or `:bufdo` to run a command on each buffer.
- `execute "normal! ..."` Run the sequence of commands after `normal!` as if they were entered in normal mode. Ignore all mappings and replace string escape sequences like `\<esc>`.
- `"+p` Paste the register for the [system clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489440/176646). Note that Vim has to be compiled with the `+clipboard` feature enabled for this to work.
- `| w` Write every file, whether it was updated or not. Alternatively, use `| update` to only write files that were changed.

For more details, see:

- [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/30.html)
- [Vim 101: Search and Replace on Multiple Files](http://usevim.com/2012/04/06/search-and-replace-files/)
- [Run a command in multiple buffers](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers)

<sub>Originally answered by [Roberto Balejík](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2195618/roberto-balej%c3%adk)</sub>