# Copying all lines to clipboard from VIM in cygwin

Tags: bash, vim, cygwin

Has anyone found a good way to copy all lines from VIM in cygwin?
I've tried yanking the lines but it doesn't go to windows clipboard.  Any ideas?

This seems to be a solution but it is a lot of work for copy/paste:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_Windows_clipboard_in_Cygwin_Vim

UPDATE:
this works:

```
echo 'put this on my windows clipboard' > /dev/clipboard
```

BUT doesn't work for me because **I want to copy to clipboard while SSH'd into another machine**.  So echo'ing/cat'ing to /dev/clipboard will put it on the other machine's clipboard, not mine

Comment: Then try `X11`-forwarding: `ssh -X`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard)

Comment: @SibiCoder there isn't a single mention of cygwin in that question or any of the answers

Comment: The question I tagged is a general one related to this question. You might find answer in that question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be better ways, but here's how I do it:

Use visual mode to highlight lines to be copied to clipboard (From command mode, `v`, then navigate normally to highlight).

```
"+y
```

to copy to clipboard.

Since the question asks how to copy everything:

```
ggVG"+y
```

Comment: I do like that. `ggVG"+y` copies everything :)

Comment: you don't really need to use visual mode to copy everything. `gg"+yG` is enough.

Comment: But then, in OP's link, it is clearly specified that `+` doesn't correspond to Windows' clipboard. So this answer will not work for Cygwin.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I just tried with my cygwin installed version of vim.exe, and gg"+yG  successfully copied to windows clipboard

Comment: @C.H. Good to know! then I wonder why vim's wiki states that `"+y`doesn't copy to Windows clipboard… or maybe something has changed recently…

Comment: @C.H. Isn't this solution the same thing as yanking but just yanking from visual mode?  Which doesn't work for windows clipboard.  I tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: @MikeSallese This is yanking to the + buffer, which is the windows clipboard. From what I've been reading you could also use * (but I haven't tested it)

Comment: @C.H. the problem may be that I'm trying to do this while ssh'd into another machine.  Because this doesn't work for me.  I updated my question

Comment: @MikeSallese: Then try `ssh -X`.

Comment: @C.H. It gives me an error noise when I do "+.  But when I highlight with my mouse and use y it works with the ssh -X

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not as easy as you wanted it to be, but here is how I usually do it myself:

```
:w
:!cat %
```

This will display your file, and you can copy it from there.