# How do I yank to system clipboard in Kakoune?

Tags: yank, kakoune

If I yank a word in [kakoune](http://kakoune.org/), how do I paste it into another editor (e.g. gedit)?

I have read [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard?noredirect=1&lq=1) since vim is very similar but kakoune does not have any `*` register.

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune/wiki/Registers-&-Clipboard) ?

Comment: Can't you [wait](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune/issues/1099) a bit?

Comment: @romainl I have thought about it but :

1) this kind of question does not fit github issue well
2) there will be probably more people who will be confused as I was

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case all the links go away this is the complete solution:

```
<a-|> xsel --input --clipboard <ret>
```

Explanation:

- `<a-|>` pipes the current selection to what follows.
- `xsel` is a program for manipulating X's clipboard.
- `--input` tells `xsel` to read from stdin.
- `--clipboard` tells `xsel` which 'selection' store to use. There are three of them and you want 'clipboard' in order to paste elsewhere.

This will work on Linux. Not sure about MacOS, I'd imagine piping to `pbcopy` would Just Work.

EDIT:
To make live easier define a key binding in *User* mode like so (in your `.kakrc`):

```
map global user y '<a-|>xsel -i -b<ret>'
```

Now you can select the text and press `,y` to yank to the system clipboard. The leading comma tells Kakoune to look for the key binding in User mode.

Comment: Actually, `--input` (`-i`) can be omitted. Default behaviour of `xsel` when its stdout and stdin are not tty is to read from stdin, and if stdin is tty then default behaviour is to write to stdout.
Also, `--clipboard` can be abbreviated to `-b`. Or omitted altogehter if you want to copy to "primary selection" rather than clipboard.

Comment: `<a-|> xsel -i -b` worked for me after installing `xsel`. Wasn't able to shorten it further. It's a shame that it's this complicated for something so simple.

Comment: @Joe I've updated my answer to provide a shorter solution.

Comment: A simple, naked `xsel` saves to primary, `xsel -b` to clip.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the accepted answer, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune/wiki/Registers---Clipboard#to-yank-copy) if your version of Kakoune is post July 2020 then you can add the following hook to your kakrc:

```
hook global RegisterModified '"' %{ nop %sh{
  printf %s "$kak_main_reg_dquote" | xsel --input --clipboard
}}
```

Comment: It's not a keybinding, it's a hook that runs xsel every time anything gets yanked, thus keeping system clipboard in sync with the main "copy" register

Comment: @usretc Thank you for your correction.  I have amended the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just so you are aware, there is also a great plugin to help with this issue. [Kakboard](https://github.com/lePerdu/kakboard) works everywhere, including Mac, Xorg and even Wayland environments. You can also set your own custom command in more exotic environments by setting the `kakboard_(copy|paste)_cmd` options.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out you need to install `xsel` and then follow [this guide](https://github.com/mawww/kakoune/wiki/Registers---Clipboard) on wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-platform, or platform-agnostic solution:

The system clipboard will update automatically when you yank.

Note, for linux, I use wl-copy for wayland.

```
hook global RegisterModified '"' %{ nop %sh{
    case $(uname) in
        Linux)
            wl-copy -n "$kak_main_reg_dquote" > /dev/null 2>&1 & ;; 
        Darwin)
            printf "%s" "$kak_main_reg_dquote" | pbcopy ;;
        esac
}}
```