# How to copy(External Sources) and paste on Vim

Tags: vim, copy, paste

I am enjoying playing with Vim but I am struggling with copy and paste.

I can copy from outside sources like url, and paste it with right click of mouse, but I want to know shortcut keyboard.

Is there way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+copy+paste+OS+clipboard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986045/how-to-use-different-registers-in-vim-to-copy-paste-from-to-os-clipboard-how

Comment: See selection and drop registers at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers : `"*` and `"+`. Commands like `"*p` and `"+p` and `"*y` and `"+y`.