# copy the whole document from vi and paste it in the notepad

Tags: vi

I have a 500 lines txt file opened in VI, i want to copy the whole file from VI and paste it in the notepad

I have tried yanking the whole document, but i dont know how to paste it in the notepad

Comment: Yanking copies to vi's internal buffer, not the clipboard. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard

Answer (score 2):

If vi(m) has access to your system clipboard:

```
ggVG"+y
```

Go to the top of your file, enter visual mode, select to the end of file, then `"+` means use the `+` register aka the system clipboard, and `y` yanks it.

Then again, if you just want the text in Notepad, why not save it as a text file and then open it in Notepad?