# vim block copy between different SecureCRT sessions

Tags: vim

I connect two SecureCRT sessions. Is there any ways or plugins to use vim's block copy paste between them?

Thanks for helping.

[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdY94.png)

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I've struggled with this in the past, and it's very platform specific.  One way to do this though would be to get all copying and pasting to go through the system clipboard by default. A similar question is here: [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard)

To sum up, confirm your vim installation is compiled with clipboard support with `:echo has('clipboard')`, and if it is, then the "* register *should* work for communication between both windows.

If this works, you can use this register automatically by adding `set clipboard=unnamed` to your vimrc (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip21)