# when an option of clipboard, "unnamedplus", is included in vimrc, E518 error says that's unknown

Tags: vim, clipboard

In order to enable vim to access clipboard when yanking, I added the following script into `~/.vimrc`.

`:set clipboard = unnamedplus`

After this, when I tried to use vim, the following error message was always shown:

`E518: unknown option: unnamedplus`

But `unnamedplus` option is common and can be seen in other stackoverflow's questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard).

Why my `.vimrc` can't find options of clipboard?

My all `.vimrc` is below:

```
1 :set autoindent
2 :set number
3 :imap <C-j> <esc>
4 :noremap! <C-j> <esc>
5 :set clipboard = unnamedplus
6 :colorscheme elflord
```

The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The version of vim is `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4` and `Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.`

Answer (score 1):

1. In general, "options" depend on "features". If Vim is not built with feature A, options depending on feature A won't be available.
2. But that's irrelevant. The problem, here, is that you put spaces around the equal sign so Vim thinks `unnamedplus` is the name of an option. The right syntax would be either:

   ```
   set clipboard=unnamedplus
   ```

   or:

   ```
   set clipboard =unnamedplus
   ```

   From `:help :set-args`:

   ```
   White space between {option} and '=' is allowed and will be ignored.
   White space between '=' and {value} is not allowed.
   ```

   The "no-spaces" version is kind of a de-facto standard.

Answer (score 0):

`set` does not allow white space after `=`.

See `:help set` for more information.

```
:se[t] {option}={value}     or
:se[t] {option}:{value}

     ... (unrelated explanations)

    White space between {option} and '=' is allowed and will be ignored.
    White space between '=' and {value} is not allowed.
```

By the way, you can omit colon when you write `.vimrc` or other Vim script files. So your `.vimrc` should be like

```
set autoindent
set number
imap <C-j> <esc>
noremap! <C-j> <esc>
set clipboard=unnamedplus
colorscheme elflord
```