# How to efficiently copy code from editor to search field in VS Code using vscodevim?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code, vscodevim

This is currently how I copy code from an editor to a search field in VS code using vscodevim.

1. Select text in editor somehow
2. Right click to open up the contextual menu (since pressing `Ctrl+C` does not seem to work on Ubuntu, even when in input mode, and 'p' does not work in the search field) and click copy
3. Press `Ctrl+Shift+F` to open the search field
4. Press `Ctrl+V`

I'm pretty sure this is not how copying from an editor to search field is intended to work. It it the steps 1 and 2 I would like to change to something better.

What is a more efficient and vim-like sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to VIM so there might be a better way using VIM commands but for now this works pretty well.

Go into insert mode with `i` than select the word you would like to search for (I'm using the mouse) and than just press `ctrl + f`. Your search window will open as usual containing the selected word in it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to search for the word under the cursor**

`Ctrl-F` will do the trick.

Or you can use Vim's `*` command, which effectively does the same, but jumps to the next occurrence right away by default.

**Otherwise**

If you need to use the search field for whatever reason, then the standard Vim way to copy stuff to the clipboard works, so you can yank into the `*` or `+` registers. The steps will then be:

1. Select text
2. `"+y` (you can create a shortcut for this combination if you want)
3. `Ctrl-Shift-F`, `Ctrl-V`

See also: [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard).

Having said that, the more obvious approach might be to use Vim's built-in search features, so after selecting the text, the remaining steps would be `y:` (yanking selection to the default register and opening the command-line) then `/` or `?` (search forward or backward), then `<C-v>` (pasting the yanked selection to the command-line - this works only in the VSCode plugin, while in Vim you should use `<C-r>"`).

Comment: except that... ctrl-V does nothing here.  this is true for both the global search (ctrl-shift-F) and search in currently open file (ctrl-F). right-click and select "paste" works.  charming. EDIT: I'm not using vscodevim, just plain vscode

Answer (score 0):

I use Command-E (on a Mac) *constantly* when editing code. This puts the current selection (or with no selection, the word under the cursor) into the search buffer.

This answers your question - Hit Cmd-E to select the search string, then Cmd-Shift-F or Cmd-F for the search dialog.

But a more common workflow for me is Cmd-E to set the search buffer, then jump straight to Cmd-G for "Find Next" or (more often) Cmd-D to "multiple cursor select", etc. Maybe set the search string in on file, then jump to another file and Find Next, etc.

Once your fingers learn Cmd-E, you'll use this approach *constantly* in many scenarios.