# How to define a shortcut to copy code from editor to search field in VS Code using vscodevim?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, vscodevim

How to create a shortcut that puts the selected text into the `vim`(!) search field. This is partially answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55302116/how-to-efficiently-copy-code-from-editor-to-search-field-in-vs-code-using-vscode). This sequence of actions is what I need

> 1. Select text
> 2. `"+y` (you can create a shortcut for this combination if you want)
> 3. Ctrl-Shift-F, Ctrl-V

My question is how to define a command to make it in one hop?