# How do I edit current shell command without executing it?

Tags: bash

There seems to be quite a lot of information on how to edit and execute a command using your editor using "edit-and-execute-command (C-x C-e)", but what I would like to achieve is take the current shell command, apply certain filtering (using a script) and then return it to prompt for further approval/manual changes before execution. Is this possible with bash?

Comment: This is not the right answer to the question, but try using [ZSH](https://ohmyz.sh/) terminal instead of the native Bash. It has auto-completion so don't execute commands straight away. I have personally tried this specific scenario and it always requires me to press enter whenever I do a `edit-and-execute-command`.

Comment: The shortcut which which works for me is `Escape`+`V`, but it's still going to execute the command. So as for the workaround, I would add `echo` in the front to execute it by printing the command to the console for review.

Comment: can you please make an concrete example? I don't understand "apply certain filtering (using a script) and then return it to prompt".

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne: zsh is not a *terminal*, it's *shell*.

Comment: `fc` (c-x c-e) to enter $EDITOR and `:cquit` cancels edit and exit without executing. works for `EDITOR=vim`. `Vim` returns non zero exit code so shell won't execute the command - read more here http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html

Comment: Comment the command M-#, bring the command back C-p, edit the command C-x C-e, and uncomment using M-- M-#.

Answer (score 10):

## Latest update based on my experience

The part `0"+y$dd` in the following mapping is really something that you should carefully think about and tailor it to your taste/workflow/experience.

For instance, very frequently I've found myself ending up with multiple lines in the buffer, where I only want to execute the one the cursor is on; in this case I can use `0"+y$dd:%d<CR>` instead of `0"+y$dd`.

And this is just one of the possible scenarios.

## Final answer for those who love `vim`

- Set `vim` as your `EDITOR`/`VISUAL`, so that when editing a command line, you will use `vim` to edit it.
- Put `au BufEnter /tmp/bash-fc.* nn <Leader>d 0"+y$dd:wq<CR>` in your `~/.vimrc` file to map <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> (which you will rarely use when editing a command) to the action "delete the current line into the `+` register without the trailing EOL".

  - [you can use either the `+` or the `*` register in the mapping above; the ways to paste into the terminal will likely differ; you need the `+clipboard` option for these registers to be available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489440/5825294).
- When finished editing a command in the `vim` editor, hit <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.
- Paste the clipboard into the terminal (this is terminal-dependent).

## Original answer

I often need to do the same, and I do it as follows. (I normally use the `set -o vi` in `bash`, so points 1 and 2 in the following are different if you use `set -o emacs`, the default; based on your question it looks like points 1 and 2 are unified in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, which is harder to type, imho.)

1. hit <kbd>Escape</kbd> to be in normal mode,
2. hit <kbd>v</kbd> to enter the editor to edit the command,
3. edit the command as I like,

(This is where you ask the question.)

4. hit <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>,

   - Note: <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>, not simply <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>, as the latter would copy the newline too, and this would result in executing the command upon pasting it in the command line,
5. paste the clipboard on the command line

   - how to do this depends on the terminal you are using, I guess; I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in `URxvt`.
6. proceed to approval/manual edit.

Clearly this is just a workaround, consisting in copying the edited command into the clipboard before deleting the whole command, so that nothing gets executed upon exiting the editor; however it's the best I can get for myself.

## Update

As my `EDITOR` (and `VISUAL`) is equal to `vim`, when I edit the command, I edit it in `vim`.

In this respect, I have noticed that the buffer is named `/tmp/bash-fc.random`, where `random` is a 6-characters alphanumeric random string.

This gives space to a lot of possiblities, if you use `vim` as your editor, as you can define some mapping in your `.vimrc` to execute the whole sequence <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>. For instance, one command that you'd rarely use when editing a command line is <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>; therefore you can put the following `map`ping in your `.vimrc` file

```
au BufEnter /tmp/bash-fc.* nn <Leader>d 0"+y$dd:wq<CR>
```

so that step 4 in the above recipe becomes

4. hit <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Now that I think about it, maybe a variation of what @kenorb suggested in a comment is the best workaround (as it seems no solution exists), if we want to stick to `bash`.

What you can do is prepend a `#` (the comment character in `bash`) to the command, rather than `echo`. Then when you exit the editor, the command will be ineffective, and you will only have to press <kbd>arrow up</kbd> (or <kbd>k</kbd>, if you use `set -o vi`), remove the `#` and confirming.

Note that this strategy adds just a few keystrokes, so it can be fairly efficient, depending on your typing level.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do that in Bash/readline but it's possible in zsh
using `edit-command-line` command:

```
darkstar% autoload edit-command-line; zle -N edit-command-line
darkstar% bindkey "^X^E" edit-command-line
```

Now press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to open your editor, edit line, leave the editor - you will see the updated command line  but it will not be executed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point you to the *Composure* framework for Bash (I'm not affiliated with it): https://github.com/erichs/composure

It provides `draft` and `revise` functions that sound like they could help with what you're trying to do. Here's a (long) quote from the project's readme file:

> Composure helps by letting you quickly draft simple shell functions,
>   breaking down your long pipe filters and complex commands into
>   readable and reusable chunks.
>
> ### Draft first, ask questions later
>
> Once you've crafted your gem of a command, don't throw it away! Use
>   `draft ()` and give it a good name. This stores your last command as a
>   function you can reuse later. Think of it like a rough draft.
>
> ```
>   $ cat servers.txt
>   bashful: up
>   doc: down
>
>   up-arrow
>
>   $ cat servers.txt | grep down
>   doc: down
>
>   $ draft finddown
>
>   $ finddown | mail -s "down server(s)" admin@here.com
> ```
>
> ### Revise, revise, revise!
>
> Now that you've got a minimal shell function, you may want to make it
>   better through refactoring and revision. Use the `revise ()` command
>   to revise your shell function in your favorite editor.
>
> - generalize functions with input parameters
> - add or remove functionality
> - add supporting metadata for documentation
>
>   ```
>   $ revise finddown
>   finddown ()
>   {
>     about finds servers marked 'down' in text file
>     group admin
>     cat $1 | grep down
>   }
>
>   $ finddown servers.txt
>   doc: down
>   ```

Answer (score 1):

These pieces might get you closer:

a) replace the the normal binding for newline newline (ctrl-M)
`bind -x '"\C-M":date"`

b) grab the current line from the history using `!#`

replace date with whatever script you want.

c) edit manually

d) if necessary, somehow tie in `!!:p` which prints the new command to the command line but does not execute it, thus letting you manually edit it.

e) using ctrl-J submit edited command rather than a newline

or they might not ....

Answer (score 1):

There is an option in bash to modify command from history without executing it. I'm not sure it it's possible to use script for this, doesn't seem to be likely. Although, you can make modifications using history modifiers.

1. Enable option histverify to prevent execution of modified command
2. Use chain of modifiers to change last command
3. Use "!!" to put your result to command line for final edit

Here is how it looks:

```
$ shopt -s histverify
$ ls *.sh
script1.sh  script2.sh  script3.sh  script-return.sh
$ !!:s/*/script1/:p
ls script1.sh
$ !!:s/1/2/:p
ls script2.sh
$ !!
$ ls script2.sh
script2.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in native bash using readline specifically READLINE_LINE and READLINE_POINT variables. I use this functionality all the time though not through vim, you would need to get the value of $selected from your vim command and if not empty it takes your original line + your input and replaces your original line with the combination without executing. output as a variable

```sh
_main() {
  selected="$(__coms_select__ "$@")"
origonal_text=$READLINE_LINE  READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$selected${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
  READLINE_POINT=$(( READLINE_POINT + ${#selected} ))
}

  bind -m emacs-standard -x '"\C-e": _main '
  bind -m vi-command -x '"\C-e": _main '
  bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-e": _main '
```

[image: asciicast]

### Edit

Just remembered these two utilities that will let you do this as well.
Vipe allows you to run your editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and edit the data that is being piped between programs.
vp, up, vipe, Neomux (upgrade of nvim terminal) you can do some pretty neat throwing buffers between the terminal and split window.
and Athame (full vim on the command line)
https://github.com/ardagnir/athame
careful with that one though plugins work on the cli and it can get funky if you got tons of plugins

Answer (score -1):

It does not seem possible with a keyboard shortcut, at least:

```
$ bind -P | grep -e command -e edit
complete-command can be found on "\e!".
edit-and-execute-command can be found on "\C-x\C-e".
emacs-editing-mode is not bound to any keys
possible-command-completions can be found on "\C-x!".
vi-editing-mode is not bound to any keys
```