# Select All + Copy/Paste

Tags: vim

A common pattern I find myself doing in a non-vim text editor is:

`Cmd` `a` `Cmd` `c`

to copy all the content in the entire file, and then open a new file and

`Cmd` `v`

to then paste in all that content. When all is said and done, I can usually do this entire copy-paste in about 0.5s. What would be the most common/efficient way to do this in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do the same quite often by running the following commands: `ggVGy`.

The first command, `gg`, jumps to the beginning of the file. Then we select the entire first line with `V`. Still in visual mode, we jump to the end of the file with `G`, before copying (yanking) everything with `y`.

You can make this even faster and easier by mapping all of these commands to one key. With the mapping below, pressing the leader key and X will copy the entire file.

```vim
nnoremap <leader>X ggVGy
```

If you need the content to be available to the system clipboard, and not only in Vim, you should use `"+y` instead of `y`. This will yank to the `"+` register used for the system clipboard. You can find more information on this topic in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard).

Comment: awesome, though it doesn't copy to my system's clipboard when I try doing `"+y` (note that I'm on a mac). Is there another way to copy to system clipboard?

Comment: I am using macOS myself, and `"+y` works for me. You can try the `"*` register instead (`"*y`), as there is only a distinction between these registers on X11 systems. On macOS (and Windows) they both refer to the system clipboard.

Comment: A shorter way to copy the whole file is: `:%y+` .

Comment: You can also run `:echo has('clipboard')` to see if Vim was compiled with the clipboard feature or not. If it returns 1, you are good to go.