# How to copy text in a remote vim session into terminal

Tags: vim

I would like to copy the following function and paste it into a shell outside vim:

[image]

Once I have selected the text I have tried doing `"+y` and it yanks the text, and allows me to copy-paste that into another vim editor, but if I try copying it into another terminal shell, it doesn't do anything. Now how I have to do it is use my mouse, remove the line numbers, and highlight those lines 37-42. What would be the proper way to yank/copy the text so I can paste it into other programs. Note that this is on a remote ubuntu server.

Note that outside of vim, I would have to use `Cmd` `p` to paste in the text (my local machine is a mac).

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make vim paste from (and copy to) system's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489428/how-to-make-vim-paste-from-and-copy-to-systems-clipboard)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+copy+paste+terminal

Comment: @phd the issue I believe is that if I then do cmd-C on the server, it will copy from my local machine instead of my remote. What's the best way to copy-paste from a remote machine?